# Treat PNG file as PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to upload a PHP file to a server under a PNG extension, while still being able to view it in my browser as a PHP file. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean view the php code itself or the rendered output?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What have you tried so far?  Are you trying to output an image from your script?

Comment: Do you have control over the server you are uploading it to?

Comment: I'm guessing he has a PHP script that has a content-type set to an image, but the special thing he wants is for the file to be named with a `.png` extension (is that right?).

Comment: You might want to look in rewrite rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703862/htaccess-rewrite-image-file-to-php-script

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in your .htaccess file in the directories where your files are:

```
<FilesMatch "\.png$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMAtch>
```

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html
- http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/745293-force-apache-parse-html-files-php

Note that ALL files with .png will be handled by PHP with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add AddType application/x-httpd-php .png to an .htaccess file (assuming your host allows you to use .htaccess files), and Apache will send those file off to be parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use URL Rewriting for this?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. PHP is server-side code and is not rendered in the browser.

Comment: What? You can configure apache to fire up the php interpreter for any file extension. You can also have it treat it as plain text so the PHP is viewable. It's not clear what OP wants.