# .htaccess rewrite image file to php script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

Here is what I have for now in my `.htaccess` and this should work in future:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The question is:

how can I make this rewrite `/tmp/some_image.png -> /image.php?file=some_image.png`

I've tried to make my own rule, but without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is /tmp a directory accessible by your web-server? I'm hoping it's a separate /tmp folder and not the actual /tmp of the server as that would be a security risk.

Anyway if the image is a physical file then you need to put this after your rewrite to force HTTPS and before the conditions checking if it's a file or directory:

```
RewriteRule ^/tmp/([^\.]+)\.png$   /image.php?file=$1.png [NC,L]
```

You could check for other extensions as well:

```
RewriteRule ^/tmp/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$    /image.php?file=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Or if you don't care (everything is an image in your tmp folder. Though i wouldn't recommend this)

```
RewriteRule ^/tmp/(.*)$    /image.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

If it's not a physical file you can put any one of these at the end of your rules.

Comment: This rule `RewriteRule ^/tmp/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$    /image.php?file=$1.$2 [NC,L]` will not work if image has a `.` in its filename eg. `file.name.jpg`

Comment: Use `RewriteRule ^/tmp/(.+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$    index.php?file=$1.$2 [NC,L]` in case you want to allow file names with multiple `.`

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is:

```
RewriteRule ^/?tmp/(.*\.png)$ captcha.php?file=$1 [L]
```

thx goes to `Humbedooh@freenode`