# Serve some PHP as a PNG file

Tags: php, url-rewriting, web, redirect

I'm currently trying to get a small script working on my server, the point would be to serve a random PNG at a certain adress, for example https://domain.me/image/.

In /image/, I have this index.php, that does the job pretty well and outputs what I want:

```
<?php
$max = 30;
$image = rand(1, $max);
$name = '/var/www/image/src/'.$image.'.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

(my PNGs are as you guessed stored in /image/src/)

I'm now trying to run that script when someone calls https://domain.me/image/script.png (some websites require a PNG extension at the end of the URL), and can't really figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using apache, you can use htaccess files to redirect your request:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule script.png index.php
```

That should redirect from index.png to index.php

Comment: Works like a charm. I was trying `RewriteRule index.php script.png` for some reason. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a LAMP server, you might be able to get it working using a url rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html.

Similar to this question: [.htaccess rewrite image file to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703862/htaccess-rewrite-image-file-to-php-script)