# Apache 2.4.34 PHP FPM rewrite problems

Tags: php

The Apache Congig

```
<Directory  /var/www/vhosts/avoclub/htdocs/avobb>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI +MultiViews

    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteOptions InheritBefore
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        #RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9056/$1
        RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9056/var/www/vhosts/avoclub/htdocs/avobb/$1 [L,P]
    </IfModule>

    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

what i am trying to do, I have a Image script that water marks the image and displays

the .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.(jpg|png)) ./image.php?filename=$1
<Files "logfile.log">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</Files>
```

it should :) request a image file .htacces rewrites it to image.php, water mark image and display.

but when u do

```
https://bbs.avoclub.com/documents/how_too/RS2_Clutch_7.jpg
```

you get File not found.

Help

Comment: It shoudn't be `RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.(jpg|png))$ /image.php?filename=$1`? Check where exactly is your file and the reference to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite image file to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703862/htaccess-rewrite-image-file-to-php-script)

Comment: will try that mate theimage.php is in same dir as the images

Comment: nope even had whole path to image.php and same File not Found

Comment: if the link is wrong you get the Not Found (404) when it is the right link u get the message File Not Found

Comment: so problem is not with `.htaccess` file, but your `image.php` script.

Answer (score 1):

Moved the

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteOptions InheritBefore
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        #RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9056/$1
        RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9056/var/www/vhosts/avoclub/htdocs/avobb/$1 [L,P]
    </IfModule>
```

out side the `<Directory>` block ! Sorted

Blue